# Where can I find logs for an Azure Static Web App?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I created an **Azure Static Web App** and **Application Insights** for the same. I ran the API in Postman. I can see the request being executed in application insights. But I can't see the logs. In the Azure Function, I have a log as shown below:

`log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");`

Where should I look to see the log `C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.`

This is how my Azure Function page on Azure Portal:

[image]

Comment: Did you open the live "Log Stream" blade in the Azure portal, you should see the log messages there. Refer [this](https://akhilsharma.work/how-to-see-log-stream-of-webserver-and-application-logs-on-azure-webapp/), this is [recent](https://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2020-08-12-getting-logs-from-static-web-apps-apis/)

Comment: The app insights resource's `key` needs to be created as a _configuration_ `setting` in your static Web App, then your azure function generated logs will be visible in that App Insights resource. This manual wiring up is needed since this is static web app, hopefully MSFT will handle this in future.

Comment: Your article directed me to a solution which I've described as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

With Azure Static Web App the logs are only available if you **add Application Insights**. ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apis-functions#troubleshooting-and-logs

[image]

Comment: Once I get into App insights, I still can't find my logs. The MS article is not helpful.

Comment: Found it -- it's in Events, then click "More"

Answer (score -1):

Go to the **Application Settings** and then the **logs**. There are some tables listed on the left. Double click **traces**. That will list all the traces including the log information.

Comment: instead of "Application Settings" you probably meant Application Insights.  This was where my logs were.  Using javascript context.log.error().  They were not in the Events tab as ulu mentioned.  Nor in the customEvents log table (but the trace table)