# Azure Static Web App remove API break site

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm attempting to play around with the static web hosting provided by Azure. I've been following this information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nuxtjs).
Which pointed me to this [repo](https://github.com/staticwebdev/nuxt-3-starter/).

I cloned this repo and got everything working fine in the static web hosting. I then installed vuetify and got that loading fine.

Next I was reading you can only support JS, and typescript functions in this configuration. Which is not what I want. I want to use c# compiled functions, so in order to do this. I need to ['bring-your-own-functions'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/functions-bring-your-own). By setting up a functions app, and then 'linking' it to the static site.

I followed all the instructions provided there. Setting the 'api_location' to an empty string, and I changed the name of the ts function from 'hello.ts' to 'hello.ts.disabled' just in case. But I don't think the last part matters really.

I confirmed all the deployment from github actions completed and it did. I then visited my site. It worked... happy days... But waiting 5 minutes, it then started returning a blue 403 error page, and for the life of me I can't see what I might have missed. I checked locks, and no issue. I checked API, and I see production and a 'link' hyperlink. Meaning no API is present anymore.
[image]

At this point I am not going to link the API until I work out why I'm getting this 403 issue. I am using standard plan, so it's not a limitation around the linking if I was to proceed.

I have not seen any authentication settings that might be related to this. As that was my first point of interest.

So has anyone else come across this issue before, and how did you work around it?

**Note**: I have not turned on insights yet, because I didn't want to pay for it. So I can't provide logs at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The github source code you are referring already has a Default API, And it requires you to set > **.output/server** > In the API Location like below:-

[image]

[image]

**In Azure Portal a managed Function is created by default like below:-**

[image]

Now, I created a workflow file with empty ***API Location = ""*** and the Deployment was successful but the site was failing, This is due to the wrong API location as this particular source code requires - **.output/server** as an output:-

When **I Linked .Net C# Http Function with the Azure static web app the API did load** Refer below:-

***Copied this Function URL to get the Function key and api route correctly:-***

[image]

**Linked this Function to my Azure static Web app:-**

[image]

**My Azure static web app URL with Function API:-**

```
https://ixx-xxxx-07xxx.3.azurestaticapps.net/api/Function1?code=<function-key>xxxu9f6kJQ==&name=sid
```

[image]

As a workaround try to use another github sample from [**here**](https://github.com/staticwebdev/) which does not include managed function

And unfortunately the only way to check the Logs in Azure static web app is via enabling Application Insights refer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71548317/where-can-i-find-logs-for-an-azure-static-web-app)

Comment: Thanks for the good reply. Unfortunately, I think it's focused on the bit I didn't have a problem with. I have already unlinked the original automatically linked functions app. The screenshot I provided shows that it has no linked API. So I would expect that Nuxt app to be just running, with no API. But what is actually happening is that it'll work for a few minutes until the caches clear, then it'll start returning a 403.  There is no mounted call to the API, and the only reference is the <NuxtLink> component in the app.vue file. 

Where is the 403 coming from?

Comment: I have to stick with Nuxt 3 start repo, as that is what the client has requested. I need to also check SSR is working etc.