# Share URL for ReactJS app hosted in Azure static web app or refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, azure-static-web-app

I currently have a ReactJS app which is hosted in Azure StaticWebApp which also calls API endpoint for backend functionalities.

I would like to share the specific URL like when you send emails so that users can directly access say https://www.google.com/Order?OrderId=100.

If I do it currently, it doesn't find the page, I'm getting a Page Found error.

I did see this [Blog](https://antbutcher.medium.com/hosting-a-react-js-app-on-azure-blob-storage-azure-cdn-for-ssl-and-routing-8fdf4a48feeb) about doing the same thing, but, it is using Azure Blob Storage and it's 4 years old blog.

How can I do this and also if the user by chance refreshes the page, getting a Page Found error.

I was able to get locally working with add "staticwebapp.config.json" with

```
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "index.html",
    "exclude": ["*.{jpg,gif,png}", "assets/*", "/.auth/*"]
  }
}
```

Now I need to get the file deployed to Azure Static Webapp.

I added the changes on the YAML file to include

```
  config_file_location: '/'
```

but build is not working adding the file to the artifacts for the frontend.

I was able to get the "staticwebapp.config.json" copied to public folder for now and that works. But, it's a fix rather than the correct solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

In order to redirect to the API in your react code you need to implement custom Functions in your Application code.

Refer this [Github repository](https://github.com/ChiliMonanta/azure-static-web-app-net-react) where C# Function with WeatherForecast and HttpTrigger is integrated with React code.

I deployed this Repository in my Azure static Web app and below are the results:-

**App and API location for above repository is set to below:-**

```yaml
app_location: "app" 
api_location: "api" 
output_location: "build
```

[image]

I have created one sample Javascript Function and that redirects to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and added it as a managed API in my sample React app like below:-

**My Javascript httpTrigger Function:-**

**httpTrigger1.js:-**

```js
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

        // Redirect the request to www.google.com
        return {
            status: 302, // HTTP status code for redirection
            headers: {
                'Location': 'http://www.google.com',
            },
        };
    }
});
```

Below is an alternative code to get the URL in the Http request instead of redirecting there:-

```js
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

        // Respond with the www.google.com URL
        return {
            status: 200, // HTTP status code OK
            body: 'http://www.google.com',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
            },
        };
    }
});
```

Deploy this Function in the Javascript Function app like below:-

[image]

Create Azure Static Web app in Standard Tier as Function API can only be added in Standard Tier and is not supported in Free Tier.

[image]

After the Azure Static Web app is Deployed> Visit API and Link your Function HttpTrigger like below:-

[image]

And call the **Static Web app URL by adding function API** like below:-

```
https://<azure-static-web-app>.4.azurestaticapps.net/api/httpTrigger1?
```

**Refer my SO thread answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77262221/azure-static-web-app-remove-api-break-site/77270658#) to use API in the Azure static web app.**

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. Appreciate it. will try to implement it and see