# Azure function app deployment to Azure and integration to Blazor web assembly

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am new to Azure functions. I have a scenario like to call the published Azure function in a Blazor wasm app using C#, using a relative published URL.

Could you please help us like how configure the `HttpClient` in the Azure function app and call the relative url from the client?

Comment: If you have deployed your blazor WASM in Azure static Web app you can add the Function directly in Azure static web app by referring the steps in my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77262221/azure-static-web-app-remove-api-break-site/77270658#77270658)

Comment: Or you can refer this [Github repository](https://github.com/staticwebdev/blazor-starter/tree/main/Api) where the Function code is added in the Api folder

Answer (score 0):

I tried calling the Azure Functions URL in **`FetchData`** but it did not fetch the value.

**`FetchData.razor:-`**

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@inject HttpClient httpClient

<PageTitle>Fetch Data</PageTitle>

<h1>Fetch Data</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from an Azure Function.</p>

@if (responseData == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <p>@responseData</p>
}

@code {
    private string? responseData;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://valleyfunc761.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            responseData = $"Error: {ex.Message}";
        }
    }
}
```

In order to achieve your task, Create your Function files like **Function.cs** inside an **API folder** by referring this [Github Repository](https://github.com/staticwebdev/blazor-starter/tree/main/Api):-

And deploy this Repository code in **Azure static web app**, You have an option to add the **Function manually or the Function inside the API folder** is added automatically as API like below:-

***Output:-***

[image]

[image]

[image]